Class that stores base value and delegates for it's modification (C#)
I'm looking for an existing implementation (preferably for C#) of a data structure (represented by a generic class) that stores a base value, a list of delegates that can sequentially (according to priority) change the base value, and a property from which the current value (base value after modifications) can be retrieved. When a new delegate is added or removed, the current value is recalculated.
What existing solutions can be used?
I wrote my own implementation for this, but I don't want to reinvent the wheel.

Same pattern used in "StoryingBoarding" (WPF/UWP). The "base" values are "pre-transform" properties ("actuals"); "current" are transformed values. The individual animations amount to delegates "over time".

@GerrySchmitz Thanks for answer! I think, you misunderstood me. I don't need the changes to happen over time, they should happen all at once.

@GerrySchmitz I work with Unity and I’d like for me to give a game example.
We have a car script with MaxSpeed(100) field. With use of my class: Processed MaxSpeed = Processed(100f)
We pick up Upgrade with method ChangeMaxSpeed(ref float value) => value += 20. We can add delegate to this method as modifier for MaxSpeed. In my case: car.MaxSpeed.AddProcessor(ChangeMaxSpeed, 1* priority *). Value is recalculated MaxSpeed.Value is 120.
And I can add more different processors with different logic and priority to modify value.

@GerrySchmitz The problem is that it will take many days of work to get my implementation perfect, and if there is an existing implementation, I would like to use it, rather writing my own.

I gave you an existing pattern as an example; food for thought; that's all. The keyword was "pattern".  And an animation can have "zero" duration; making it "happen at once" (at say a specific time or other property dependency).  I calculate "max speed"; it's a bit more involved; there are multipliers for " object type"; ascent; descent; terrain; gait; loss of strength; short and long-term fatigue. The default for a multiplier is simply "1.0". Regardless of the implementation, you need to be able to "specify" the "model". It can't operate without "input" (which is what storyboarding is).

An approach to get you started:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic; 

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var bob = new ValueAndModifiers<int>(5);
        
        bob.AddModifier(z => z + 5);
        bob.AddModifier(z => z * 2);
        
        Console.WriteLine(bob.GetCurrentValue());
    }
}

public class ValueAndModifiers<T>
{
    private T initialValue;
    private List<Func<T, T>> modifiers = new List<Func<T, T>>();
    
    public ValueAndModifiers(T initialValue)
    {
        this.initialValue = initialValue;
    }
    
    public void AddModifier(Func<T, T> modifier)
    {
        modifiers.Add(modifier);
    }
    
    public T GetCurrentValue()
    {
        var value = initialValue;
        
        foreach (var modifier in modifiers)
        {
            value = modifier(value);
        }
        
        return value;
    }       
}

This will recalculate the value every time you ask it.
Other approachs / optimisations are possible. Perhaps do the calculation each time AddModifier is called. Perhaps cache the result in a Lazy<int> and reset the lazy every time AddModifier is called. Many approaches will work - which is right depends on your consumption patterns.
Note - this implementation is not thread-safe as it stands.
